# Control native component measurement and layout in React Native

Tags: android, video, reactjs, react-native, android-fullscreen

In React-Native, Can we increase height/width of a view such that it can layout outside of parents bound ?

> I want to make a view fullscreen that is several layers down a
>   hierarchy e.g. an item of a listview..

For Android. especially..

I have tried setting layout params but doesn't work, layout sizes can only be modified from JS.

> In React-Native Repo's source code,  I have seen stuff like
>   LayoutShadowNode that can help you provide custom measure function.
>   But I applied it to my custom native component and measure method
>   never gets called.

Here is a link to a similar description of issue : https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-video/issues/170

Also tried steps mentioned in 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/5148
but does not seem to work.

Comment: have you found out any solution for this problem? I am having same problem and I do not know how to force component size from Java code.

Comment: see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4990 and the issue 170 mentioned in the question, those should help you I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure but you can try something like this and see if it works.

```
int width = 200; // arbitrary width and height values
int height = 200;
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
Objects.requireNonNull(reactContext.getCurrentActivity()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
view.measure(width, height); //the view/layout you want to resize
view.layout(-screenWidth, -screenHeight, width, height); // giving first 2 parameters negative value is the key here
```